# What is the best way to store slide-out sidebar menu data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a sidebar menu in my application (like facebook's one) and currently I have hard coded the categories of my sidebar. My question is the following : what is the best place to store the data of that menu?

1. Hardcoded like I have done actually?
2. SQLite database?
3. plist file?

I am asking that because I would like to keep in memory in which menu I am, and I wonder if database would not be the better way to do that?

Thanx in advance

Comment: try to check here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=slide+menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just mean the categories of the menu itself, then hardcoding is fine depending on how likely they are to change. But if it's like facebook and they don't change, then it's fine.

In terms of the content that is displayed when you tap a menu item, that's different. There I'd recommend either a SQLite database, or better yet use CoreData to manage it for you.

If you have a view controller manage the state of that menu, you can keep in there which menu item you have selected, keep a list of items to display etc and that's fine, no need for a database there really. What I would suggest though is something flexible so that you could easily add new items.

For example one app I worked on, I created an array of `NSDictionary` objects that each had a title, image, and selector. When it came to rendering the list, I simply looped through the list, created a new item with the title and icon, and when the user tapped in called the selector. This way, if we needed new menu items, I could just add a new item to the array and that was it.

I had this array hard coded in the controllers initialiser, but you could if you wanted serialise this into a plist file, but that's just a preference thing

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I will try the hardcoded NSDictionary then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Plist` or `hard coded dictionary` as its not relevant to save this in `sqlite` or `coreData`.It is not efficent to save this in database as to fetch each time you need to do database operation.

This data will not take too much memory so you can hardcode as you did and keep in memory.I think it is also on your controller that each time on side menu it remains in memory or each time you press button it will load.If it is not loading each time than your menu categories remain in memory.